# Hidden checkbox into button without id using Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm going nuts trying to click on a checkbox hidden into a button. The HTML code is the following one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys5xQ.jpg)

What I'm trying to do is to select the button and check the box with the code

```html
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frmBusquedajurisprudencia"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a/label/input').click()
```

And returns ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable.

My hypothesis are, the checkbox is hidden (not in the DOM) so fristly I have to click the button and after doing so clicking the checkbox but I'm not sure how is it done.

My second hypothesis is that the element of input is not clickable and I rather should focus on the li element as when I check the bpx the class of the li renders "active".

All answers will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the website shareable?

Comment: Of course, https://www.poderjudicial.es/search/indexAN.jsp

Comment: This should bypass the popup as well as click the appropriate items.

Answer (score 0):

To simply open the element click on the button with the multiselect tag and then click the label with input value of CIVIL.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get('https://www.poderjudicial.es/search/indexAN.jsp')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.close"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[@class='multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default tooltips'])[1]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[.//input[@value='CIVIL']]"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[image]